# Trigger to update the Contact Owner depending on Email field value

Tags: trigger

I'm new to coding and I'm practicing by creating a trigger that will update the Contact Owner depending on the Email field value.

For example, I have the Email field value is *test@gmail.com* then it will try to look for User that has *test@gmail.com* email then it will update the Contact Owner.

This is what I've done so far:

```
trigger AutoChangeOwner on Contact (before insert, before update) {

    Set<String> conEmail = new set<String>();
    Map<String, Id> UsrMap = new map<String, Id>();

    for(Contact con : trigger.new ){
        conEmail.add(con.Email);
        system.debug('conemail' + conEmail);
    }

    List<User> userEmail = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User WHERE Email != null];
    for(User u : userEmail){
        if(conemail.contains(u.email)){
            UsrMap.put(u.Email, u.Id); 
            system.debug('useremail' + userEmail);
        }
    }

    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        c.Text__c = UsrMap.get(c.Email);
    }

}
```

The code is compiling without any error but the Owner field is not getting updated when I change any field in contact. Any ideas?

Any kind of explanation, code snippet, best approach to achieve my goal is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with a well-bulkified trigger; this is a good start. The error

> Illegal assignment from Set to Id

comes from this line:

```
        c.OwnerId = UsrId;
```

`OwnerId` is a single Id field; `UsrId` is declared as a `Set<Id>`.

The chief problem you seem to have here is mapping between email addresses and user Ids. What you need is a `Map` here:

```
for(User u : userEmail){
    UserList.add(u.Email);
    UsrId.add(u.Id);
}
```

These `Lists` don't do you any good. Instead, create a new variable typed as a `Map<String, Id>`. As you loop through User records, add each to the map:

```
myMap.put(u.Email, u.Id);
```

(Note for later that you don't have a solution here if more than one User has the same Id).

Then, when you loop over Contacts,

```
    if(conEmail == UserList){
        c.OwnerId = UsrId;
    }
```

You don't want to do this, because you're comparing the whole sets `conEmail` and `UserList`, and what you're interested in is *this* Contact, `c`. But if you have the Map described above in hand, you can use the user's email address to look up in that Map what its new `OwnerId` should be:

```
if (myMap.containsKey(c.Email)) {
    c.OwnerId = myMap.get(c.Email);
}
```

Using a Map also ensures that your code doesn't run slowly by iterating needlessly over records that do not match because Map lookups are *constant-time*: the time required to check the value corresponding to some key is constant, and doesn't grow with size.

Comment: Thank you so much @David this will add up to my knowledge.

I've updated the code and I'm having errors. What's the possible cause of the error?

Comment: @Naofumi it's containsKey, sorry. My mistake!

Comment: Thanks again @David the code is compiling without any error but the Owner field is not getting updated when I change any field in contact. Any ideas?

Comment: is my query correct? I think the reason why it's not updating is because it fails to get the User that has the same Email _conEmail_

Comment: @NaofumiKun did you figure this out? It might be helpful to run some queries in Developer Console or add logging.

Comment: sorry for the late response, yes I'm still having issues.

Code above is updated, I've checked the debug log and I'm not seeing any traces of `useremail`

Comment: To add up I'm getting null assignment to Text__c

`|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[21]|this.Text__c|null|0x2238376b`